# Can I test an instant app deploy from bundles locally?

Tags: android, testing, android-instant-apps, android-app-bundle

It is possible to test the installable App Bundle with bundle tool.
https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/bundletool

```
bundletool build-apks 
bundletool install-apks
```

Recently Google added the ability to publish Instant Apps in App Bundle format.
Is there any way to test instant app deploy from bundles locally? 
smth like

```
bundletool deploy-apks
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found updated documentation.

https://developer.android.com/topic/google-play-instant/getting-started/instant-enabled-app-bundle

```
bundletool build-apks
unzip base.apks
$ANDROID_HOME/extras/google/instantapps/ia --debug run splits/*.apk
```